# What will it be if SqlConnection.Close() or SqlConnection.Dispose() is not called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I just found that one `ASP.NET` web application in my company would connect to a `SQL Server 2008 R2` database to read/write data, but in some part of codes, both `SqlConnection.Close()` and `SqlConnection.Dispose()` are never called after using the connection.

From MSDN, [SqlConnection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose.

I use `sp_who` and find that more and more connections are created as I perform some database access via the web application. But after a few minutes, some connections seems dropped.

Is there anything `.Net` runtime done to handle such case that `SqlConnection.Close()` and `SqlConnection.Dispose()` are not called? And is there any potential problems which affect the performance and stability?

Comment: maybe it is wrapped by a `using` statement which is an alternative.

Comment: Not only Close, you can also call Dispose, it means this connection will be closed and disposed. The right pattern always use "using (SqlConnection....) {...}".

Comment: Eventually they are disposed by the garbage collector but this doesn't mean that you should ignore the problem. Leaving the connection open means that your server consumes its own resources for every ghost connection and this could be a really big problem in a high load server. Try to use the using statement around every connection object

Comment: how about `using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnectio())` ?

Comment: Both `Close()` or `Dispose()` are not called in the code. In fact I would like to know if there are any potential problems, because I have already used and test this program for a few weeks but no connection problems occurred.

Comment: That code will show its problems when your server is under a lot of stress and in any case your server is performing poorly (less than optimal at least) because it keeps around memory, threads and sockets for nothing. Of course the problem is present also on client machines and you will face intermittent and inexplicable errors (sooner or later) that will make your head poor of hairs. Trust us. Search your code and add the using statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will of course fix it. I was just wondering is `.Net` has any mechanism to handle such case:p

Comment: .Net handle that case, but is take time to decide to release the resource that you have request, because is not sure if you still using them or not.

Comment: [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can run out of available, connections, on the client or on the server.  The best method is to declare the connection with USING, unless you are declaring the connection in a function in which it is returned (that's a gotcha that I've seen where Using was added everywhere by a zealot.  Another pattern is that in a function where the connection drops out of scope, have a try catch with finally holding con.close

Answer (score 0):

It will go OK and you won't get any error for some time.
As your application runs and each time you open a SQL connection and keep it non closed, after sometime you SQL connection pool will got full and system throws connection pool overflow error as you try to open a new SQL connection.

So always keep a connection close code within your function.